# What does it mean of the subtraction between number and matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have a number and a matrix. I performed the subtraction between the number and the matrix. It worked. However, it does not make sense in mathematics. So, how to understand that process in MATLAB? For example,

```
A=[1 2 3; 4 5 6];
B=max(A(:))-A;
```

What is meaning of B? On other hand, if I subtract a number which is maximum of matrix and its matrix, what is  meaning of result? 
Thanks

Comment: Not a mathematical question, rather stackoverflow. Anyways, MATLAB does a lot of point-wise operations by default, so if I'm not mistaken, you will get [5 4 3; 2 1 0] as a result. You can easily check it. In mathematics the difference or sum between matrices of different dimensions is not defined.

Comment: You are got a true result. Could you explain the meaning of result B?

Comment: it's a difference between [6 6 6; 6 6 6] and A. Hopefully you did not make me to summon anything

Comment: As my test, I found that the above equation looks like equation of Maksim Maisak. I think that in Matlab or anything, they tried to make a rule look like that

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, the result is equal to $max(A)J-A$, where $J$ is a matrix of ones, equal in size to $A$.

Comment: It looks correct sir. I tested it. Thanks